# Which version of Amdgpu?

Tags: amdgpu, gpu-driver, amdgpu-pro

I would like to know, which console command shows me the current proprietary amdgpu driver version installed. Somehow -after a bit of research- it is a bit of a secret.

Comment: Did you install the "pro" version?

Comment: Nope, I did not install anything yet. It is the "stock"  version that comes with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: If it is about amdgpu from the kernel, there is no "version" of it besides the kernel version.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu is not like Windows, where each piece of hardware has a separate installable driver with its version.

Most of hardware is supported directly by the Linux kernel, that contains drivers almost for everything including AMD GPUs.

So there is no `amdgpu` version that comes with Ubuntu.

Comment: Great thx, but let me clarify: AMD is offering amdgpu version (latest in my case 19.30 for my RX 570) to download. I am not talking about pro version. Does it make sense to install this one or is it (almost) the same provided by the linux kernel?

Comment: This provides Amdgpu Pro driver.

Comment: Here we go: [link](https://www.amd.com/de/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-570)

Comment: You need to search Amd site and ask them what is the difference in their "all-open" and "pro" driver compared to in-tree kernel driver. You won't find that Ubuntu has version X and they provide version Y of the drivers.

Comment: You can try to install them and see if there is any improvement.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. Help me a lot.

Comment: https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-overview.html#stack-variants explains all-open and pro driver.

Comment: It doesn't explain difference between in-tree kernel driver and the one provided with the package.

Comment: Yes you are right, but at least it explains the difference between the other two. I installed all - open on my machine. Right now everything looks fine.